# Merging Row Header Cells in DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I created a DataGrid. I dont know how to Merge Row Header Cells

I want the output as following,

```
....................................................................
............|.....1.....|.......2.....|.....3......|....4....|......
|           |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|  MON      |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|...........|...........|.............|............|.........|......
|           |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|  TUE      |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|...........|...........|.............|............|.........|......
|           |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|  WEDS     |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|...........|...........|.............|............|.........|......
|           |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|   THU     |...........|.............|............|.........|......
|...........|...........|.............|............|.........|......
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to redo that post - I couldn't even begin to edit what you want there!

Comment: Are you shore you talking about DataGrid... maybe you using DataGridView?

Comment: It appears to me that you want to embed a datagrid inside the cells of datagrid.  Is this for ASP, Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly merge cells with a normal `DataGridView`.

I suggest to switch to another type of object (there are some opensource grids that allow this) or else you will have to handle with the `'CellPainting'` event of the `DataGridView`

If you choose the second option check these :

- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=539476
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/5b659cbd-7d29-4da4-8b38-5d427c3762e2/

but as you can see, this solution is not clean.